# How to use resources in XAML from .resources files (not .resx files)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have tested a small WPF program where I have specified the GUI text in two different resx-files (Resource1.resx and Resource1.sv-SE.resx). This way I can change the language of the GUI to Swedish or English.

But now I'm trying how to use a .resources file instead of a .resx file (created with ResourceWriter() ).

But I can't get it to work. I have verified with resgen that the .resources file have the correct data.

Any tutorials or info how to do this?

And why do I want to do this? I have been assigned an older project that uses .resources to translate GUI text. And I want to learn how it works with a small project at home :-) But I tested with .resx files first, and that works.

This is how it looks when I get it to work with .resx files:

[image: My little WPF test projekt]

Comment: Rick click on the file, then properties, what's the value of the build action property?

Comment: Build Action is set to Embedded Resource

Comment: And what's the name of the class and namespace?

Comment: My simple program is called WpfApplication1, so the namespace is WpfApplication1? What class do you mean?

Comment: I want to be able to get strings from the ResourceX.resources (look at picture in first post). That is the trouble I have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.resources` files are not intended to be used in `XAML` the same way as `resx`.

Unlike resx, which is readable XML data, `.resources` is binary. They are to be embedded in a runtime executable or compiled into a satellite assembly.

To read data from .resources file, you need to do it in C# code, by using  [ResourceReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcereader(v=vs.110).aspx) class.